# is index required on distinct(count(ColumnName)) with index on where clause?

Tags: mysql, indexing, sql, query-performance

I have a table like this

```
Subscribers
  Id (PK, int)
  OwnedBy (FK, int)
  EmailAddress (varchar 50)
```

If I query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(EmailAddress))
FROM Subscribers
WHERE Subscribers.OwnedBy = 67;
```

There is an index on the `OwnedBy` column. Assuming the table is very large, should I also index `EmailAddress`? I am not concerned about write performance degrading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you should.

Since your query can be rewritten like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Subscribers
WHERE Subscribers.OwnedBy = 67
GROUP BY EmailAddress
```

you should have a look at the MySQL `GROUP BY` performance optimization pages:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-optimization.html

There, the following is stated:

```
The most efficient way to process GROUP BY is when an index is used to 
directly retrieve the grouping columns
```

So if you are not concerned about insert/update performance and size of the table you should definitely go with an index on `EmailAddress`

Comment: Thank you. Can you comment on your solution versus creating a covering index as mentioned by Omesh?

Comment: Maybe this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213235/mysql-covering-vs-composite-vs-column-index

Answer (score 1):

You should create covering index to make it even faster.

```
ALTER TABLE Subscribers ADD KET ix1(OwnedBy, EmailAddress);
```

Check status as Using where Using Index with this query:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(EmailAddress))
FROM Subscribers
WHERE Subscribers.OwnedBy = 67;
```