# Preferable index structure in mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following database structure:

- id
- name
- year
- director
- runtime

An example entry being: (1, "Titanic", 1994, "James Cameron", 02:44:00)

I want to find a match by any three of the four criteria, for example:

```
1. name + year + director
2. name + year + runtime
3. year + director + runtime
```

If I created one index, would that be sufficient for optimial queries?

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD INDEX (name, year, director, runtime)
```

Or, do I need to create an index for each combination?

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD INDEX (name, year, director)
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD INDEX (name, year, runtime)
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD INDEX (year, director, runtime)
```

I would obviously prefer to use the first, but which would be suggested here? Why would one be preferable to the other? This is an InnoDB table.

Comment: You could add a FULLTEXT index on all 4 columns and search with WHERE MATCH(all 4 columns) AGAINST (words) IN BOOLEAN MODE

Comment: @Mihai I'm using InnoDB.

Comment: On 5.6 or higher you can use FULLTEXT on innoDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that `id` is a primary key having default unique index; if you create one index  with 4 columns that would be sufficient cause in that case what you are getting is a `Covering Index`.

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD INDEX (name, year, director, runtime)
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation, could you please explain what a `Covering Index` is and how that's useful?

Comment: A covering index refers to the case when all fields selected in a query are covered by an index, in that case **InnoDB** (not MyISAM) will never read the data in the table, but only use the data in the index, significantly speeding up the select.

Comment: @David542, see this SO thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213235/mysql-covering-vs-composite-vs-column-index as well as MySQL docs http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html

Comment: This search `year + director + runtime` wont use your index

Comment: @Mihai why wouldn't it?

Comment: @David542 The first column in the index needs to be the same with the LEFT column in the search.http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html If the search conditions are with AND ,the index will be used if the index starts with any columns in the search(not the case here)