# MySQL Indexes: composite vs column

Tags: mysql, indexing, innodb, database-administration

I Have gone through some Q&A eg.

[How does database indexing work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108/how-does-database-indexing-work)

[Mysql covering vs composite vs column index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213235/mysql-covering-vs-composite-vs-column-index)

These are good reads, But I got some more question about Indexes ie.
Assuming below table and Execution plans:

```
CREATE TABLE student(`id` INT(9), 
                            `name` VARCHAR(50),
                            `rollNum` INT(9), 
                            `address` VARCHAR(50), 
                             `deleted` int(2) default 0,
                            Key `name_address_key`(`name`,`deleted`),
                            Key `name_key`(`name`)
                            );
```

Plan 1: `explain select * from student where name = "abc" and deleted =0;`

its shows key = `name_address_key`

Plan 2: `explain select * from student where name = "abc"`

its also shows same key = `name_address_key`

my question is :
How MySQl decide the index for execution plan?

Answer (score 1):

Since the `name` column is a prefix of `name_address_key`, that index can be used for matching `name` just as well as `name_key` can. There's no reason for it to prefer one over the other, and but the cardinality of `name_address_key` is presumably higher, so it chooses that one.

There's no point in having `name_key`, since it's redundant with `name_address_key` and just wastes space.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect it to pick `name_key` since the size of the index is smaller.

I would recommend removing `name_key` as being essentially useless, as @Barmar discusses.

Don't us 4-byte `int` for flags (`deleted`), see `TINYINT` and other smaller datatypes.

Do have a `PRIMARY KEY`.

Another good read (in my biased opinion):  [*Indexing Cookbook*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/building-the-best-index-for-a-given-select/)