# What is a MySQL covering index?

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-performance, covering-index

I saw the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/glossary.html#glos_covering_index) describing covering index:

> covering index
>   **An index** that includes all the columns retrieved by a query.

Does it mean that the covering index is a specific index?

**I think covering index is a phenomenon.**

If i follow the description of the document, then please see the following sql statement:

```sql
create index idx_name_age on table（id, name）
select id, name from table where id = 1
select id, name, age from table where id = 1
```

`idx_name_age` is a covering index in first statement, the second one is not.

So I think instead: the covering index is a phenomenon rather than **an index**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql covering vs composite vs column index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213235/mysql-covering-vs-composite-vs-column-index)

Comment: I revised the question again. I read the answer to Johan in the question you refer, his answer to the `covering index` is different from the definition of the document.

Comment: I have not idea what you mean by phenomenon in this context.

Comment: Let's say it is "an attribute of an `INDEX` _relative_ to a particular `SELECT`."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say that "covering" is "an *attribute* of an INDEX *relative* to a particular `SELECT`.

Some examples:

```
select id, name from table where id = 1

    INDEX(id, name)       -- covering; best index
    INDEX(id, name, age)  -- covering, but overkill
    INDEX(age, name, id)  -- covering, but inefficient (might not be used)

select id, name, age from table where id = 1

    INDEX(id, name, age) -- Having `id` first is optimal, but any order is "covering"
```

As already pointed out, if this is InnoDB and the table has `PRIMARY KEY(id)`, then none of these secondary indexes are worth having.

```
SELECT a FROM tbl GROUP BY b ORDER BY c

    No index is very useful since the GROUP BY and ORDER BY are not the same.
    INDEX(a,b,c)   -- in any order, is "covering"
    INDEX(b,c,a)   -- "covering", and perhaps optimal.
    INDEX(b,c,a,d) -- "covering", but 'bigger'
```

Bigger matters in small ways.  When doing `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...`, InnoDB will (usually) pick the 'smallest' index to do the counting.

Another 'rule' is to avoid redundant indexes.

```
    INDEX(a,b)  -- Let's say you 'need' this one.
    INDEX(a)    -- Then this one is redundant and should be dropped.
```

Answer (score 2):

> is the covering index is a specific index?

**Yes**, it is an index purposefully designed to satisfy particular queries.

For this query

```
select id, name, age from table where id = 1
```

the covering index is a multicolumn index on `(id, name, age)` created by

```
create index idx_name_age on table（id, name, age）
```

How so?

`id` is the first column in the index because it's used in `WHERE id = 1`. It's first because MySQL indexes are generally BTREEs, randomly accessible in index order. So `WHERE id = 1` can jump, in the index, to find those `id` values.

`name` and `age` also appear in the index because they appear in the `SELECT` clause. Because they are in the index, *the query can be satisfied entirely from the index.* This is good because it cuts down on reads from disk or ssd: MySQL doesn't have to use the index to find rows in the main table before it can satisfy the query.

An index on only `(id, name)` is *not* a covering index for the above query; the `age` column is missing.

This query

```
select id, name from table where id = 1
```

can also be satisfied from the (`id, name, age)` covering index. It also can be satisfied by an index on `(id, name)`: that *is* a covering index for the second query (but not the first).

Your example illustrates of the glossary definition. Indexes gain query performance by using extra disk/ssd space to store data.

A Microsoft SQL Server user can declare an index like this:

```
create index idx_name_age on table (id) include (name, age)
```

In this index the values of `name` and `age` ride along with the `id` in the index, but the index isn't ordered by those included columns. So, updating the index takes less time.

If `id` is the table's primary key, none of this applies, either in MySQL's InnoDB or SQL Server. The table itself is an index on `id`; it's sometimes called a clustered index. But now we're getting into too much detail.

Covering indexes can provide **phenomenal** increases in query performance when used wisely.  Read https://use-the-index-luke.com/  For indexes to help, you must design them to match your queries. That's a large part of the art of database optimization.