# Wordpress WP_Query->get_posts() slow Queries on MySQL 8?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, query-optimization

I have a new simple Wordpress Site. Just a few plugins, much posts but for some reason it loads really slow on the page. (Backend is okay, when i go on posts site)

I think its the combination of MySQL 8 or something...

Did someone has same experience and ideas how to fix it? With Caching, it loads good, but without, its much to slow and looks not normal as i what i know about wordpress.

Example:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships
ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
WHERE 1=1
AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (215,216,227,228,229,230,231,232) )
AND ((wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
OR wp_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled'
OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private')))
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

this query loads 0.5s
Sounds not much but there also other queries and combined it is 4s loading time which its not normal.

Probably i need to setup my.cnf for mysql or something? i dont know, hope someone can help me?

I changed few cnf settings, trying different plugins and already googled for these problem but doesnt find something

Comment: Try the [Index WP MySQL For Speed](https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/) plugin. It creates an index that may [cover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57606332/what-is-a-mysql-covering-index) the `wp_posts` table for this query.

Comment: @O.Jones thanks for trying helping me! I tried it, doesnt help in the performance. Did you have an idea what the best mysql8.0 and php7.4 settings for wordpress? I have 32GB RAM, 10 Cores Server

Comment: I'll be happy to try to help, but through the support forum for the plugin I mentioned. Please read  [this](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/please-when-you-report-a-problem-or-ask-for-help/).

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.  View profile for contact info.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.