# Mysql Recursive CTE and two left joins are making the query run extremely slowly. How to optimize the query?

Tags: mysql, database, query-optimization

```
SELECT
    t.id,
    t.name,
    t.email,
    t.parentId,
    SUM(d.volume) AS total_volume
FROM (
    WITH RECURSIVE users_path (id, parentId, name, email, path) AS (
        SELECT id, parentib AS parentId, name, email, name AS path
        FROM users
        WHERE parentib = 72
        UNION ALL
        SELECT c.id, c.parentib, c.name, c.email, CONCAT(cp.path, ' > ', c.name)
        FROM users_path AS cp
        JOIN users AS c ON cp.id = c.parentib
    )
    SELECT *
    FROM users_path
    ORDER BY path
) AS t
LEFT JOIN account a ON t.id = a.userid AND a.isdemo = 0 AND a.active = 1 AND a.disabled = 0
LEFT JOIN live5.deals d ON a.number = d.login AND (d.action = 0 OR d.action = 1) AND d.entry = 1 AND d.time >= "2023-10-01" AND d.time <= "2023-10-24"
GROUP BY t.id, t.name, t.parentId
ORDER BY t.path;
```

- Users table has 31K Records
- Account has 36K Records
- Deals has 5854K Records

`id` field of `users` table is same as `userid` field of `account` table. Thats why `account` table is left joined with `users` on that column. Also `number` column of `account` table is same as `login` column of `deals` table, thats why another left join on that column.

The above  query is taking 1 minute to execute. Even for 1 month of data. It's taking too much time.

Please help. Can something be done to optimize this query? Following is the Explain

[image]

Comment: Do you need to use LEFT JOIN rather than INNER JOIN? INNER JOIN usually performs better.

Comment: EXPLAIN doesn't show any keys being used. Make sure you have keys on all the columns you join on. When columns between two tables are the "same", you should declare it as a foreign key.

Comment: Left join is required to have all rows from the recursive CTE. 
Any method to optimize this query.

Comment: As I said, make sure you have all the necessary indexes. It's slow because it can't find any indexes to use. Notice all the empty `possible_keys` values.

Comment: Sir Indexes creation will not slow down the insert? this deals table gets updated sometimes like 50-100 times per second. 
Also should I create indexes on column used for join? or columns used to for join as well as "WHERE" condition column as well?

Comment: It's a tradeoff. Indexes slow down inserts a tiny bit, but they speed up queries greatly.

Comment: First find out which part of your query is slow. Start with the subquery and run it alone. Then add other parts of the query until it gets slow.

Comment: To give useful advice about your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions and index definitions in addition to the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Comment: Your questions amount to "please teach me relational database design theory", which is far beyond the scope of stackoverflow. Research terms such as OLAP and OLTP

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach to optimizing this query. It's based on some guesswork because you haven't provided your table and index definitions.

I'll address your biggest table first.

Your biggest table is `deals`, and your explain output shows it's getting a (slow) [full table scan](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/table-scan-avoidance.html) to satisfy your query.  So a [covering index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57606332/what-is-a-mysql-covering-index) will help.

From that table your ON clause does equality matching on `entry` and `action`, then range matching on `time`. You use `login` to join back to your `account` table, then your SELECT clause sums `volume`.

So, this BTREE index might [accelerate](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html) your query.

```sql
CREATE INDEX entry_action_time_login_volume ON live5.deals
    (entry, action, time, login, volume)
```

It's a BTREE index, so its first three columns allow the query planner to random-access it to the first useful row, then [range-scan](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/range-optimization.html) it, the index, sequentially to the last useful row. That saves the full table scan. The query planner doesn't examine rows with dates outside the range you want. That saves CPU and IO work when running the query.

The last two columns of the index contain data needed by the rest of your query. That means the planner doesn't need to do another operation to fetch the data, and can get it directly from the index.

It's not 100% certain this index will help, and it may need adjustment. Once this index is in place, you can examine your performance and EXPLAIN output again. It's possible the index needs tweaking in the order of columns. And, it's possible other tables need indexes.

Teaching you to do this analysis is beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow answer. Read Markus Winand's excellent https://use-the-index-luke.com/ e-book.