# How to fast return and count rows from one table based on filter by two another tables

Tags: php, mysql, performance, filter, database-performance

I have 3 tables:

**products (1 500 000 rows)**

```
+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|     id     |     shop    |    brand    |   category  |
+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+

id int(11), AI, PK;
shop int(11);
brand int(11);
category int(11);
```

**tags (1 300 000 rows)**

```
+------------+------------+-------------+
|     id     |   product  |     tag     |
+------------+------------+-------------+

id int(11), AI, PK;
product int(11) - it's id from 'products' table;
tag int(11);
```

**sizes (1 300 000 rows)**

```
+------------+------------+-------------+
|     id     |   product  |     size    |
+------------+------------+-------------+

id int(11), AI, PK;
product int(11) - it's id from 'products' table;
tag int(11);
```

Every column has index.

I need to filter all products (including count rows) which may be filtered by brand,shop,category,tag,size. So, for example if i need to just show products where brand=1 and shop=1 I will not use **tags** and **sizes** tables. It's simple. But the problem is, when I would like to show all products which are in some categories, some shops, has some brand, some tags and some size.

There are many combinations to cache all of them and update. Get live count costs about 6 second. To show all filtered products is fast because of limit for paggination.

I have spent more then week to test what is faster, which option and structure of database is better but definitely don't know to make it faster than this:

```
select p.id
  FROM
products p
  INNER JOIN tags t ON(p.id = t.product and tags=2) 
  INNER JOIN sizes s ON(p.id = s.product and sizes in (1,2))
  WHERE
p.shop in (1,13,31,65)
  and 
p.category in (270,126,127,144,143,145,146,839,147,148,149,150,158,151,155,157,123,124,128,129,602,120,121,122,152,153,154,482,526,40,42,46,115,119,138,142,133,135,136,137,130,131,132,116,117,32,103,485,112,113,114,566,39,107,108,109,110,118,265,516,527,528,529,530,106,159,161,185,30,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,267,531,532,104,105,28,29,31,33,34,35,36,37,38,41,43,44,45,102,165,269,487,2)
  GROUP BY p.id
```

There are now only 1,5M products and the filtering based on category which has 200k products (because of top of tree) is loading (counting and showing data) about 5s. It's because filtered products has result of 13k rows in category of 200k products. But still need to compare and search in all data tables. One of solution could be to separate all products to f.e. 10 table categories (for clothing, electro, drug store, food...) and search just there. But I don't think it's the best solution for the problem. Only better then now.

Doing result of this SQL with the  `order by p.id DESC limit 0,120` is pretty fast. About 0,8s but count them in some case is about 8-12s. Is there any chance to get faster the result and count by changing SQL query or changing structure of DB?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: "Every column has index" is not necessarily the optimal solution to use indexes. A covering index might improve speed (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213235/mysql-covering-vs-composite-vs-column-index)

Comment: Do you need all the data at once? Limiting the fetched rows might be also helpful

Comment: A good way to experiment with the indexes, and the covering indexes Luuk suggested, is to use [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-explain.html).

Comment: @Luuk I'll try and let you know.

Comment: @MetaPakistani as i said, i don't need to use all data only 120 of them per one page. BUT, if i want to know how many pages show and as well use the number in title of category, i need to count all of them.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I have used EXPLAIN but don't really understand how to use it to change my query.

Comment: While there are many things that you can optimize including primary keys, indices and the sql query, if fesible, I will suggest storing the related tables' count number along with categories/shops and periodically updating them via corn

Comment: @MetaPakistani did you read it till the end?
PKs are there, storing (as i mentioned caching) is not possible because of too many combinations and it doesn't make sense to have updated product every month. Products are changing hourly.

Comment: In last paragraph, you mentioned that limiting the results is pretty fast but when you include counting then it bumps to 8s, I am saying that instead of counting them dynamically in query, pre-process and store the counting related which you can fetch statically

Comment: @MetaPakistani Yes, I understand you. But I don't know what all combinations user will use. Prepare all combinations of filter which every product has. It's all combinations of all categories inside the product is (may be 100) and combinations of shop and brand (3 combinations because one brand and one shop per product and may be f.e. shop- brand; shop; brand) that everyhing in combinations of all of sizes (if the product has some, but may be about 20 sizes)

Comment: @MetaPakistani continue of message: and ALL of this with combinations of tags. Now you know, why caching the count of products is not possible? It may be 20B of rows. It'll takes me two month to come again to update first product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try to make separate caches for all types of filtering. For example:

```
$tagProductIds = $yourCachingSystem->getAllIdsByTag($_POST['tag']);
$sizeProductIds = $yourCachingSystem->getAllIdsBySize($_POST['size']); 
$categoryProductIds = $yourCachingSystem->getAllIdsByCategory($_POST['category']); 

//...other filters by the product table

$neededProductIds = array_intersect($tagProductIds, $sizeProductIds, $categoryProductIds
//...other filtered ids
);

return $yourOrm->fetchAll(" ... product.id IN ($neededProductIds)");
```

2. You can create MySQL tables using the [MEMORY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html) engine. These tables are stored in the RAM and maybe this will speed up the extraction of data.

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists  `products_tmp`
(
   //cols and indexes
) ENGINE = MEMORY
SELECT * products; //tags, sizes
```

Comment: 1. Interesting solution. I will try. 
2. Don't understand. Do you mean to use in comb. with option nr. 1 or it's the second option. Will the result 100% or just "what memory remember"?

Comment: The second solution is an alternative one. Create copies of tables on the MEMORY engine and select from them.
But you will need to keep the tables in RAM up to date. If you are updating "products", you should also update the products_tmp. After rebooting the server, the tables will also have to be recreated.

Comment: OH MY GOD! The same but wrote as opt. 1 is 0,3s!!! Thank you so much for this different view of problem. :)

Comment: You're welcome:) You may also need to warmup the cache. To do this, you can use CRON with:
foreach($tags as $tag) { 
$yourCachingSystem->getAllIdsByTag($tag);
}